# Flutter Firestore- How to filter users with several search criteria

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to navigate to another screen that shows a list of Firestore users based on a search criteria. The previous screen allows someone to select exactly what type of user they are looking for based on many different search criteria. What is the best way to implement this in Flutter.

Comment: What are those criteria?

Comment: age range, name, state , city, gender, ethnicity, schedule availability for each day, and a whole bunch of sport specific performance metrics that are stored as strings in Firestore. @AlexMamo